# Is the text segment of a process off-limits?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, architecture

I'm really new to architecture and OSs so I thought I'd play around to get a sense of things, and I was trying to see if I could print the text portion of the process memory.

As I understand it, the memory goes "text || heap || unitialized || stack", with addresses increasing left to right. So if I start with some address in the stack and just move down, I should eventually hit the text.

So I wrote this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s='a';
    long int i=0;
    unsigned char* byte_array= &s;
    while (1){
        printf("%02x",*(byte_array-i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Which happily prints out a bunch of gibberish hex, than an astounding amount of 0s, then has a segmentation fault. My guess is that the 0s are the unitialized data - but why can't it keep going and read the text segment? Does a process have read access to its own code? If so, why can't I reach it?

To check that it isn't reading its code before the big run of 0s, I opened up the executable file as hex, picked a random short substring, and searched for it in the output of my program. It wasn't there.

If a process can read its own code, how could I do that?

This is running on OS X 10.11.6, compiled with clang, if that changes things.

Comment: C does not required code to read in ways it should not. `printf("%02x",*(byte_array-i));` is _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Comment: Nothing says that the segments has to be put next to each other. There could, for example, be holes in the address space for unused heap that has not been mapped (yet). That would give you a segmentation fault. That in addition to going out-of-bounds on `s` and using the wrong format specifier for a `char`. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way for a program to figure out where it's various memory sections are being kept? Is there a different recommended format (besides char) to just look at the bytes in memory?